# Add more fields to a tree view in Odoo

Tags: view, tree, odoo

I'm need to display some additional fields of related model of `account.move` like `journal_id.code`.

I'm not sure how to do it. Some answers here and Odoo's forums ([1](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/use-multiple-model-in-one-form-view-151209), [2](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/how-do-set-multiple-models-in-single-form-view-131575)) recommends to use computed fields. Reading the ORM documentation I inherited the model `acoount.move` and added the fields with `related` attribute but display an error when I open the view.

```
class new_account_move(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.move'

    partner_name = fields.Char(related='partner_id.name', store=True)
    journal_code = fields.Char(related='journal_id.code', store=True)
```

```
<record id="view_report_fourtenn_one_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">reportfourtenone.tree</field>
    <field name="model">account.move</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Report 14.01">
            <field name="invoice_date"/>
            <field name="amount_untaxed"/>
            <field name="partner_name"/>
            <field name="journal_sub_type"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="view_report_fourtenn_one_tree">
    <field name="name">Reporte 14.01</field>
    <field name="res_model">account.move</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_report_fourtenn_one_view"/>
</record>
```

The error with this approach is when I click on the `menuitem` that call the record `view_report_fourtenn_one_tree`.

```
Error:


Traceback:
compute@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:322:55
evalModifier@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:1200:91
_evalModifiers@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:1203:44
_registerModifiers@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:1404:101
_renderBodyCell@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:2089:70
_renderRow/$cells<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:2113:117
_renderRow@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:2113:80
_renderRow@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:2023:69
OdooClass.extend/Class.include/</prototype[name]</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/719-fee0a2c/web.assets_common.js:3864:371
_renderRows@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:2114:99
_renderRows@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:2024:53
OdooClass.extend/Class.include/</prototype[name]</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/719-fee0a2c/web.assets_common.js:3864:371
_renderBody@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:2084:71
_renderBody@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:2018:76
OdooClass.extend/Class.include/</prototype[name]</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/719-fee0a2c/web.assets_common.js:3864:371
_renderView@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:2117:575
OdooClass.extend/</prototype[name]</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/719-fee0a2c/web.assets_common.js:3861:488
_renderView@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:2027:79
OdooClass.extend/Class.include/</prototype[name]</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/719-fee0a2c/web.assets_common.js:3864:371
_render@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:1409:222
_render@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:2017:655
OdooClass.extend/Class.include/</prototype[name]</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/719-fee0a2c/web.assets_common.js:3864:616
start@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:1079:26
OdooClass.extend/</prototype[name]</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/719-fee0a2c/web.assets_common.js:3861:488
start@http://localhost:8069/web/content/727-9eea4b0/web.assets_backend.js:1984:405
OdooClass.extend/Class.include/</prototype[name]</<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/719-fee0a2c/web.assets_common.js:3864:616
_widgetRenderAndInsert/<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/719-fee0a2c/web.assets_common.js:4103:52
```

Error in browser console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unknown field state in domain
    compute http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/domain.js:68
    evalModifier http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/basic/basic_model.js:2220
    _evalModifiers http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/basic/basic_model.js:2229
    _registerModifiers http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/basic/basic_renderer.js:553
    _renderBodyCell http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js:423
    cells http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js:838
    _renderRow http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js:837
    _renderRow http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_editable_renderer.js:1164
    OdooClass.extend/Class.include/</prototype[name]</< http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:123
    _renderRows http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js:858
    _renderRows http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_editable_renderer.js:1185
    OdooClass.extend/Class.include/</prototype[name]</< http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:123
    _renderBody http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js:375
    _renderBody http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_editable_renderer.js:1090
    OdooClass.extend/Class.include/</prototype[name]</< http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:123
    _renderView http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js:971
    OdooClass.extend/</prototype[name]</< http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:90
    _renderView http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_editable_renderer.js:1220
    OdooClass.extend/Class.include/</prototype[name]</< http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:123
    _render http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/basic/basic_renderer.js:592
    _render http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_editable_renderer.js:1053
    OdooClass.extend/Class.include/</prototype[name]</< http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:133
    start http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/abstract_renderer.js:37
    OdooClass.extend/</prototype[name]</< http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:90
    start http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_editable_renderer.js:115
    OdooClass.extend/Class.include/</prototype[name]</< http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:133
    _widgetRenderAndInsert http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/widget.js:433
    promise callback*_widgetRenderAndInsert http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/widget.js:427
    appendTo http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/widget.js:193
    _startRenderer http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/abstract_controller.js:456
    start http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/mvc.js:124
    OdooClass.extend/</prototype[name]</< http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:90
    start http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/abstract_controller.js:84
    OdooClass.extend/</prototype[name]</< http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:90
    start http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/basic/basic_controller.js:59
    OdooClass.extend/</prototype[name]</< http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:90
    _widgetRenderAndInsert http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/widget.js:433
    promise callback*_widgetRenderAndInsert http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/widget.js:427
    appendTo http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/widget.js:193
    _startController http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/action_manager.js:853
    _executeAction http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/action_manager.js:314
    promise callback*_executeAction http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/action_manager.js:313
    _executeWindowAction http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/action_manager_act_window.js:314
    promise callback*_executeWindowAction/< http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/action_manager_act_window.js:312
    promise callback*_executeWindowAction http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/action_manager_act_window.js:257
    _handleAction http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/action_manager_act_window.js:402
    OdooClass.extend/Class.include/</prototype[name]</< http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:123
    _handleAction http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/action_manager_report.js:164
    OdooClass.extend/Class.include/</prototype[name]</< http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:123
    doAction http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/action_manager.js:165
    promise callback*doAction http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/action_manager.js:157
    do_action http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/abstract_web_client.js:273
    _openMenu http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/web_client.js:239
    completed http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/web_client.js:215
    on_menu_clicked http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/web_client.js:214
    lock http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/concurrency.js:195
    promise callback*exec/this.lock< http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/concurrency.js:194
    exec http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/concurrency.js:193
    on_menu_clicked http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/web_client.js:213
    promise callback*on_menu_clicked http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/web_client.js:210
    proxy http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/mixins.js:277
    trigger http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/mixins.js:224
    _trigger_up http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/mixins.js:339
    _trigger_up http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/mixins.js:341
    trigger_up http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/mixins.js:334
    _trigger_menu_clicked http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/menu.js:112
    _on_secondary_menu_click http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/menu.js:139
    on_secondary_menu_click http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/menu.js:55
    jQuery 8
    start http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/menu.js:62
    OdooClass.extend/</prototype[name]</< http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:90
    _widgetRenderAndInsert http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/widget.js:433
    promise callback*_widgetRenderAndInsert http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/widget.js:427
    prependTo http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/widget.js:267
    instanciate_menu_widgets http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/web_client.js:122
    promise callback*instanciate_menu_widgets http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/web_client.js:112
    show_application http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/web_client.js:81
    start http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome/abstract_web_client.js:147
domain.js:68:23
```

Note: it's running on docker container and Firefox (incognito).

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Oh and remove `ayphuteclocalization.` (your module's name?) from the record `id`.

Comment: You should close the `invoice_date` field tag.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a copy&paste mistake. I just edited the question fixing it and adding the error.

Comment: Try to see the actual error in chrome console, and its better to activate developer mode with assets

Comment: @CharifDZ I just added the browser console.

Comment: Okay the related field that you defined uses states attribute in the original module, you need to set it to `None` or empty dictionary to prevent odoo from adding `attrs` based on state field, `states=None, readonly=True, store=True`  its better to make related field readonly to prevent side effects

Comment: @CharifDZ I added `states=None, readonly=True, store=True` and tried with `states={}`  and `domain=""` too but it does not works.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well in my question, what I need is display a new list with each record in __Customers > Invoices__ with some more fields (that are related with it). I don't know if what I'm doing is the best approach to do it.

Comment: Oops i didn't notice this you need to add the state field to your list, you can hide it but its required by almost every field in the model. Even if you don't want to show it, and read about primary mode in views it my help you more in creating a copy of original view and you can add more fields

Comment: I did copy all view (tree) from the original views, even I copied the states from the original (from related fields) model but it still does not works. I did test it in Chromium, the error there is a bit different: `Error: Unknown field state in domain`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222127/discussion-between-christian-m-and-charif-dz).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error adding the field that the error specifies in my tree.

In my case the error was `Error: Unknown field state in domain`. So, I just need to add `state` field to my tree view.

```
<field name="state"/>
```

That's all.

*Note: Add `optional="hidde"` or `invisible` attributes to hide the field in the tree view.*